# Tika in Python Azure Function

Tags: java, python, azure, apache-tika

I'm trying to create a function on Azure Function Apps that is given back a PDF and uses the python `tika` library to parse it.
This setup works fine locally, and I have the python function set up in Azure as well, however I cannot figure out **how to include Java in the environment?**

At the moment, when I try to run the code on the server I get the error message

> Unable to run java; is it installed?
>   Failed to receive startup confirmation from startServer.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isnt possible at this time. To solve it, I abstracted out the tika code into a Java Function app and used that instead.

Comment: Any chance you have this somewhere that I could take a peek at ?